# Pulling only one column of Google spreadsheet on initial query/table draw

Tags: javascript, dom-events, google-docs, google-docs-api

I've tried searching for this, and haven't found any similar question here.

I'm probably missing something obvious - I'm really a web designer who gets asked to do programming stuff that I've never learned...

Basically, I've got my user selection queries working perfectly, see here: http://umbc.edu/_bwtech/api2.html

But when the page first loads, it loads all of my table columns - but I only want it to pull the first column.

I thought I had it working here: http://umbc.edu/_bwtech/api6.html
But then the user query no longer works.

How do I draw just one column without losing access to the data in the entire table for user selected queries?

If its easier if I copy the code in here, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I just needed to move my placement of:

// Apply query language statement.
    query.setQuery('SELECT A');

out of the sendAndDraw function.

Final JS is below:

```
var isFirstTime = true;
var options = {'showRowNumber': true};
var data;
var queryInput;

// To see the data that this visualization uses, browse to
// http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=rYQm6lTXPH8dHA6XGhJVFsA
var query = new google.visualization.Query(
    'https://docs.google.com/a/umbc.edu/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Akd-rqu1ZR70dDYxUEtFdGVadENqN09kT01pdklRbXc&pli=1#gid=0');

 // Apply query language statement.
query.setQuery('SELECT A');

function sendAndDraw() {
  // Send the query with a callback function.
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }
  data = response.getDataTable();
  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('querytable'));
  table.draw(data, {'showRowNumber': false});
  if (isFirstTime) {
  init();
  }
}

function setQuery(queryString) {
  // Query language examples configured with the UI
  query.setQuery(queryString);
  sendAndDraw();
  queryInput.value = queryString;
}



google.setOnLoadCallback(sendAndDraw);

function init() {
  isFirstTime = false;
  (new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'))).draw(data, options);
  queryInput = document.getElementById('display-query');
}

function setQueryFromUser() {
  setQuery(queryInput.value);
}
```